# Trying to upgrade code to work with Python 3.10 with Tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get some code from https://github.com/AntonMu/TrainYourOwnYOLO.git to run with Python 3.10. I know the github page says python 3.6 or 3.7. However i managed to get the code to run with python 3.9 and
Keras-2.4.3
tensorflow-2.5.0

However I could never go above the tensorflow and keras versions show above.
Now Python 3.10 requires higher versions

The error is shown below , but I don't know where to start looking any ideas ?

```
022-03-05 18:42:21.056749: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:828] layout failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
2022-03-05 18:42:21.112875: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:828] remapper failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
2022-03-05 18:42:21.429968: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:828] remapper failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Subshape must have computed start >= end since stride is negative, but is 0 and 2 (computed from start 0 and end 9223372036854775807 over shape with rank 2 and stride-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1377, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1360, in _run_fn
    return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
  File "C:\Users\andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1453, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    return tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(self._session, options, feed_dict,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Could not find variable conv2d_54/kernel. This could mean that the variable has been deleted. In TF1, it can also mean the variable is uninitialized. Debug info: container=localhost, status error message=Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv2d_54/kernel)
         [[{{node conv2d_54/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Could you please upgrade to tf 2.7/2.8 and let us know if this si still an issue

Comment: I found it.  It  was an issues with tensor flow above 2.5. the fix was to change       
#import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K
to
import tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend as K